# Open a custom post type in a specific custom wordpress template by clicking the post heading in another page template

Tags: php, wordpress

This is slightly hard to explain so my apologies if this question is hard to follow.
I have a custom post type for product reviews and I have created a custom template in which to display the summary views of all the products being reviewed (this is based off page.php).

I have this page working as it should, but now I want the user to be able to click one of the product summaries and have that custom post (product review) open in another template (adaptation of single.php) to see the product review in detail.

I hope this makes sense.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already the default functionality of Worpdress. [Please review this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates#Custom_Post_Type_Templates)

1. archive-{post_type}.php

   If your custom post type were 'product', and/or query_var = "product", WordPress would look for archive-product.php to display the archive of posts.
2. single-{post_type}.php

   If your custom post type were 'product', and/or query_var = "product", WordPress would look for single-product.php to display the single or permalink of the post.

This is all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy! My post_type is product_reviews and I have a custom template called single-product_reviews.php but when I click the post title permalink it opens in single.php.  Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Ah, My Bad.  I had the post_type name wrong and was using the label.  I changed the name of the single-{post_type}.php and it's now working.  Thanks so much, I knew that it would be easy but just had not come across it before.